# Discrepancies between unique users count in Google Analytics portal and result I am getting from BigQuery. Is something wrong with the query?

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, bigdata

I am trying to match users count in both google analytics and BigQuery export and understand which number is more accurate.
I have created the following query

```
SELECT
  count(distinct fullvisitorid)
FROM
 `<TABLES>_*`
where
  _TABLE_SUFFIX between "20190507" and "20190514"
  and totals.visits = 1
```

I still get a couple of percents differences. I.e. `323812 (BQ)` vs `324567 (GA)`.
Do I need to modify my query somehow to match GA number or which number is more accurate and where does the discrepancy coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users count is a bit tricky to measure in Google Analytics. Usually, the discrepancies are around 1% due to the way Google Analytics does pre-calculations. Any of the standard reports would use daily pre-aggregated tables. As such while you can add-up metrics like pageviews and sessions across days, you can't add up users since the same user could be counted for Day 1 and Day 2 etc, inflating the metric (this is what usually seen in GA). To fight this without full users re-calculations across various reports in GA, Google does estimations (HyperLogLog++ algorithm - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) for the number of users. It is very close.

I would trust numbers you are getting from BQ.

Answer (score 0):

When counting users, Google Analytics takes all rows into account. You should remove `totals.visits = 1` for user count. This contradicts session count where you need `totals.visits = 1` - so if you need both you can do something like

```
SELECT
  COUNT(distinct fullvisitorid) as users,
  SUM(totals.visits) as sessions,
  SUM(IF(totals.visits=1, totals.hits, 0 )) hitsInValidSessions
FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_yyyymmdd`
```